# Firebase Hosting redirect to Function + Angular Web App

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have an Angular app deployed to Firebase Hosting, now I am writing a function with express.js and deploying to Firebase Functions. The problem is the `rewrite` section of the `firebase.json` doensn't work as I expect it to after deploying.

Relevant code snippets:

`firebase.json`

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "/api/**",
      "function": "main"
    }, {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }]
  }
```

`index.ts`

```
.
. //Imports and functions
.

app.get('/ping', (req, res) => res.send('Hello from the other side'));
app.post('/contact', contact);

export const main = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The Angular app loads perfectly fine, but everytime I try to hit the functions api (`/api/**`), it throws a 404.

```
https://my-app.firebaseapp.com/api/ping // FAILS
https://us-central1-my-app.cloudfunctions.net/api/ping //THIS WORKS
https://my-app.com/api/ping //FAILS
http://localhost:5000/my-app/us-central1/main/ping //RUNNING LOCALLY. THIS WORKS
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. A push in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

P.S: I've also mapped a custom domain to Firebase Hosting and am trying to access the functions using `https://my-app.com/api/ping`.  The Angular app loads fine at `https://my-app.com`

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find any solution? Thanks